# Spring boot jar loading

Tags: java, spring, classloader

By default if we add jar plugin as dependency to our spring boot app, spring can load these dependenies. But how can I configure spring to load my custom jar plugin from custom paths.

Comment: Assuming you are using maven, you can add your custom repositories in <repositories></repositories> tag and continue to use custom jars. Spring will download the jars from mentioned repo.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom paths"? Is it a web URL (i.e., maven remote repository) or a local file/folder path?

Comment: as file/folder path. I want to load jar plugins dynamically without  mv install

Comment: You can use [`system`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) scope, but it is not advised since it will break CI pipelines.

Comment: I want to add my jar plugin to my custom path ex: file/lib. And If I restart the app Spring should load this jar plugin also. I mean it is dynamically

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. If you want or need to un/load the plugin dynamically then you have to use custom classloaders. If not, then simply add the `-jar your-plugin.jar` directive to the command you start your application with and the bootstrap classloader will take care of loading the required class representations. In the first case you might also want to read up on OSGI which can be [configured to coop with Spring](https://medium.com/@amitbhoraniya/spring-boot-with-osgi-25d2387a459e)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a custom jar from local, you may want to try through the "URLClassLoader".

Here is a simple example of loading a class from jar file.

```java
@Test
public void demo() throws Exception {
    String location = "the-path-to-your-jar";
    Path path = Paths.get(location);
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{path.toUri().toURL()});
    classLoader.loadClass("your-class-full-qulify-name");
}
```

---

### Here is update.

If you need to load all classes, then you can use `JarFile` to find all classes in a jar.

```java
public Set<String> getClassNamesFromJarFile(File file) throws IOException {
    Set<String> classNames = new HashSet<>();
    try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file)) {
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry jarEntry = entries.nextElement();
            if (jarEntry.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }
            String jarName = jarEntry.getName();
            if (jarName.endsWith(".class")) {
                String className = jarName.replace("/", ".");
                classNames.add(className);
            }
        }
        return classNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. With this classloader I can. But it loads only a class. I want to configure spring to load all classes and create beans also.

Comment: You can use `JarFile ` to find all classes in a jar, the example I have updated.

Comment: Thank you, but after getting classes I need register them as beans. But I want to do this automatic without code.

Comment: If you want to load classes into a bean container, normally we use the annotation `@Bean`. Clearly, it doesn't suit here. So after getting the class name, you can load the class by `URLClassLoader` just like the example that I gave, and it will return a `Class<?>` object. Then you can inject bean by `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar `, I wrote an article (with Chinese, you may need through the translator) about bean injection in 2.1. the article link: `https://great-jin.github.io/java/spring/ioc`.

Comment: Thank you, I read your article. And now, I have problem with registering beans conditionally with @ConditionalOnProperty and others. But while registering with BeanDefition I can not do.